# Codeigniter- Consulta no banco de dados sempre retornando null

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

A função getlocal que é uma consulta no banco de dados está sempre retornando null mesmo após eu fazer um insert no banco

arquivo denuncia_model.php

```
class denuncia_model extends CI_Model {
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

}
public function insertlocal($local){
    $insertquery = "INSERT INTO local(estado,lng,lat) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $this->db->query($insertquery,$local);
}
public function getlocal($local){
    $queryteste = "SELECT * FROM local WHERE estado = ? AND lng = ? AND lat = ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($queryteste,$local);
    $row = $query->row_array();
    $id = $row['id'];
    return $id;

}
public function insertdenuncia($denuncia){
    $insertdenunciaquery = "INSERT INTO denuncias(descricao,data,forma,genero,preconceito,idade,id_local) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $this->db->query($insertdenunciaquery,$denuncia);

}
```

}

```
    $local = array($estado,$lng,$lat);
        $denuncia = array($descricao,$data,$agressao,$gender,$preconceito,$age);
        $this->denuncia_model->insertlocal($local);
        $id = $this->denuncia_model->getlocal($local);
        array_push($denuncia,$id);
        $this->denuncia_model->insertdenuncia($denuncia,$local);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aparentemente não está retornando nada na consulta. Você confirmou se o seu insert está funcionando primeiramente? Se puder postar um var_dump direto do $this->db->query de cada função ajuda também.

Comment: O id_local ta vindo NULL, veja se tem algum erro de sintaxe nele.